# Get other user locations

Tags: android

we are developing an android application for our thesis

my questions:

1) how could we make the application detect other users that are using the app?
2) how could we display the location of the users on the map?

Can anyone give us necessary codes?

we would be very thankful 
thanks :D

Comment: *Can anyone give us necessary codes?* No, it's your thesis, not ours. You are welcome to ask specific questions when you encounter problems here. But you have to do your work and research on your own. StackOverflow isn't a magic codegenerator. ;) Heres a small start for your research: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest asking for the user's data on a welcome screen in order to use the app.
2. By sending the location of the users, storing it in a DB, and then allow each user to get a Map with those geopoints. You'll need a Cache on some point.